# Glassfish timer service: what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb-3.0

I'm trying to set a timer for a Stateless EJB in Glassfish 2.1:

```
@Stateless(mappedName = "ServiceEJB")
public class ServiceEJB implements ServiceEJBRemote {

  // other methods ... 

  // defining the timer
  @Schedule(second="*/15", minute="*", hour="*")
  public void test(){
    System.out.println("++++++++ timer!!! ++++++++++++++++++++");
  }

}
```

From what I've read, all I need to do is deploy the application and this should work. I was expecting to see in the log the printed text from the method test (every 15 seconds).  Are there any other steps I need to take in order for this to work?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you able to create a static initializer to confirm that the class is actually loading?  eg static {System.out.println("LOADED ServiceEJB class");}

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right EJB version? The `@Schedule` annotation is new with EJB3.1 whereas Glassfish 2.1 ships with EJB3.0.

Comment: @jowierun - the class loads as expected

@musikk - I'll try with GF3.0.1 and get back here.

Comment: @musikk: you're right, I tried with GF3 (EJB3.1) and it works exactly as I thought. If you put your comment as an answer I'll vote & select your answer ;) Thank you!

Comment: @Bogdan: I'm glad I could be of help. I wasn't sure how easy it is to upgrade Glassfish components to unsupported versions. That's why I only commented.

Comment: It's not easy; see my next question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439865/how-do-i-upgrade-an-existing-enterprise-project-from-java-ee5-to-java-ee-6-in-net). I made a brand new ejb 3.1 project to test timers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following my comment to the question:

The `@Schedule` annotation is a feature of EJB 3.1. Glassfish 2.1 uses EJB 3 whereas Glassfish 3 uses EJB 3.1 and therefore should be suited better.