# How do I upgrade an existing enterprise project from Java EE5 to Java EE 6 in Netbeans (6.9)

Tags: java, netbeans, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, java-ee-5

The project has an EJB module & a web module. Changing the server is easy, but I'd like to switch to EJB 3.1 also but I believe I need to change all kind of configuration files since I can't do it from the project properties window(s).

Any tips or links do useful documentation will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently it's not that complicated. It worked for me by modifying the following files:

**`<project-folder>`/nbproject/project.properties**
change the following lines:

```
j2ee.platform=1.5
javac.source=1.5
javac.target=1.5
```

to

```
j2ee.platform=1.6
javac.source=1.6
javac.target=1.6
```

Repeat the same for:

**`<project-name>`/`<project-name>`-ejb/nbproject/project.properties**

**`<project-name>`/`<project-name>`-war/nbproject/project.properties**

In ejb-jar.xml change the line:

```
   <ejb-jar xmlns = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         version = "3.0"
         xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd">
```

to

```
<ejb-jar xmlns = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         version = "3.1"
         xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd">
```

Next, find `persistence.xml` and change this line:

```
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
```

to

```
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
```

Comment: When updating to Tomcat 7 you should use: j2ee.platform=1.6-web