# How do I downgrade an existing project from Java EE5 to J2EE 1.4 in Netbeans (7.0.1)

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, java, java-ee-5

I've created a new (Web Application) project in Netbeans 7.0.1 and set the Java EE version to **Java EE 5**. The options that I then have for the Source/Binary Format (Project Properties > Sources > Source/Binary Format) are **JDK 5 and 6**.

If during creation I set the Java EE version to **J2EE 1.4**, then the options that I then have for the Source/Binary Format include **also JDK 1.2, 1.3 and 1.4**.

Is there any way after I've created a project with Java EE version set to **Java EE 5** to change **down to J2EE 1.4**, so that I can use Source/Binary Format 1.4? It is not available as an option in project properties.

Of course I can re-create the project using the existing sources, but I wondered if there is a more straigh-forward way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tried to fix the problem by changing the following lines in **nbproject/project.properties**:

from:

```
j2ee.platform=1.5

javac.source=1.5

javac.target=1.5
```

to:

```
j2ee.platform=1.4

javac.source=1.4

javac.target=1.4
```

I don't know if is is OK to change it manually, will try and see if it is enough and does not cause any other problems.

Comment: Seems to work OK after this change. A similar solution has been given in this post for the opposite process (upgrade J2EE version):

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439865/how-do-i-upgrade-an-existing-enterprise-project-from-java-ee5-to-java-ee-6-in-ne

In my case no extra xml files (persistence.xml, etc.) existed, so the only one needed to change was project.properties.

So, I'll set this answer as the accepted one, unless another less 'manual' way is found in the future.