# Upgrade NetBeans web project Java EE version to Java EE 7

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish

I wish to upgrade the Java EE version of my Java Web project (JSP & MySQL) to Java EE 7 (it was Java EE 5). I'm using NetBeans 8.2 and Windows 10. I have edited the project.properties file (found in Files/nbproject) with the following settings:

```
j2ee.platform=1.8
javac.target=1.8
javac.source=1.8
```

The entry for 'endorsed classpath' is empty:

```
endorsed.classpath=
```

The entries in NetBeans Project Properties for Server and Java EE version are blank (see screenshot)

[image: NetBeans Project Properties]
The project runs OK (I am using Glassfish 4.1.1) but I've no idea if its running as a Java EE 1.5 project or what.  I'd still rather resolve this issue.

I tried upgrading the Java EE version by creating a new project from existing sources (where you can set the Server and Java EE version right at the beginning of the new project) but that just led to some confusing results so I'd rather not pursue that route just now.
Oh, and I've already done web searches and looked at S.O but can't find an answer.

The complete project.properties file is as follows:

```
auxiliary.org-netbeans-modules-css-prep.less_2e_compiler_2e_options=
auxiliary.org-netbeans-modules-css-prep.less_2e_enabled=false
auxiliary.org-netbeans-modules-css-prep.less_2e_mappings=/less:/css
auxiliary.org-netbeans-modules-css-prep.sass_2e_compiler_2e_options=
auxiliary.org-netbeans-modules-css-prep.sass_2e_enabled=false
auxiliary.org-netbeans-modules-css-prep.sass_2e_mappings=/scss:/css
auxiliary.org-netbeans-modules-whitelist.whitelist-oracle=false
j2ee.platform.classpath=${j2ee.server.home}/modules/endorsed/javax.annotation-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/endorsed/jaxb-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/endorsed/webservices-api-osgi.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/bean-validator.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/cdi-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.batch-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.ejb-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.el.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.enterprise.concurrent-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.enterprise.concurrent.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.enterprise.deploy-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.faces.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.inject.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.interceptor-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.jms-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.json.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.mail.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.management.j2ee-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.persistence.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.resource-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.security.auth.message-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.security.jacc-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.servlet-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.servlet.jsp-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.servlet.jsp.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.transaction-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.websocket-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.ws.rs-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.xml.registry-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/javax.xml.rpc-api.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/jaxb-osgi.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/webservices-osgi.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/weld-osgi-bundle.jar:${j2ee.server.middleware}/mq/lib/jaxm-api.jar
j2ee.platform.embeddableejb.classpath=${j2ee.server.home}/lib/embedded/glassfish-embedded-static-shell.jar
j2ee.platform.wscompile.classpath=${j2ee.server.home}/modules/webservices-osgi.jar
j2ee.platform.wsgen.classpath=${j2ee.server.home}/modules/webservices-osgi.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/endorsed/webservices-api-osgi.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/jaxb-osgi.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/endorsed/jaxb-api.jar
j2ee.platform.wsimport.classpath=${j2ee.server.home}/modules/webservices-osgi.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/endorsed/webservices-api-osgi.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/jaxb-osgi.jar:${j2ee.server.home}/modules/endorsed/jaxb-api.jar
j2ee.platform.wsit.classpath=
#Sat Feb 20 15:33:57 GMT 2016
javadoc.splitindex=true
lib.dir=${web.docbase.dir}/WEB-INF/lib
build.classes.excludes=**/*.java,**/*.form
javadoc.author=false
j2ee.platform=1.8
dist.war=${dist.dir}/${war.name}
javac.target=1.8
build.generated.dir=${build.dir}/generated
resource.dir=setup
build.web.excludes=${build.classes.excludes}
war.ear.name=ScotiaCruisesV5.war
j2ee.compile.on.save=true
debug.test.classpath=${run.test.classpath}
build.dir=build
javac.deprecation=false
persistence.xml.dir=${conf.dir}
j2ee.copy.static.files.on.save=true
test.src.dir=test
junit.selected.version=4
includes=**
jar.compress=false
annotation.processing.processors.list=
javadoc.version=false
build.classes.dir=${build.web.dir}/WEB-INF/classes
dist.dir=dist
javac.source=1.8
javac.debug=true
javac.test.processorpath=${javac.test.classpath}
run.test.classpath=\
    ${javac.test.classpath}:\
    ${build.test.classes.dir}
build.generated.sources.dir=${build.dir}/generated-sources
javadoc.notree=false
runmain.jvmargs=
source.root=src
platform.active=default_platform
javadoc.preview=true
j2ee.deploy.on.save=true
annotation.processing.enabled=true
war.content.additional=
dist.javadoc.dir=${dist.dir}/javadoc
client.urlPart=
javadoc.additionalparam=
javac.classpath=\
    ${libs.MySQLDriver.classpath}
javadoc.noindex=false
webinf.dir=web/WEB-INF
annotation.processing.enabled.in.editor=true
javadoc.private=false
javadoc.encoding=${source.encoding}
build.test.classes.dir=${build.dir}/test/classes
jspcompilation.classpath=${jspc.classpath}\:${javac.classpath}
web.docbase.dir=web
javac.compilerargs=
source.encoding=UTF-8
dist.ear.war=${dist.dir}/${war.ear.name}
j2ee.server.type=gfv3ee6
conf.dir=${source.root}/conf
annotation.processing.run.all.processors=true
compile.jsps=false
excludes=
javac.processorpath=\
    ${javac.classpath}
build.test.results.dir=${build.dir}/test/results
display.browser=true
endorsed.classpath=
javadoc.use=true
build.web.dir=${build.dir}/web
javadoc.nonavbar=false
war.name=ScotiaCruisesV5.war
javadoc.windowtitle=
javac.test.classpath=\
    ${javac.classpath}:\
    ${build.classes.dir}:\
    ${libs.junit_4.classpath}:\
    ${libs.hamcrest.classpath}
src.dir=${source.root}/java
annotation.processing.source.output=${build.generated.sources.dir}/ap-source-output
debug.classpath=${build.classes.dir}\:${javac.classpath}
```

The web.xml file begins with the following line:

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
```

Comment: GlassFish 4.1.1 is a Java EE 7 app server, so that is the version of the APIs that you are using. When you deploy your app, it will be running on a Java EE 7 platform, just like if you started a Java 6 app on Java 8. The advantage to changing the version in NetBeans is that it will provide support for new APIs in the IDE. The app itself needs no changes to be run on a later app server.

Comment: I should also point out that the line `j2ee.platform=1.8` is definitely wrong; Java EE 8 hasn't been released yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I upgrade an existing NetBeans Java EE 6 Web project to Java EE 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17586372/how-do-i-upgrade-an-existing-netbeans-java-ee-6-web-project-to-java-ee-7)

Comment: Thankyou - I just changed the entry to '1.7' and it appears to have solved my problem.

Comment: I had thought the entry `j2ee.server.type=gfv3ee6` was problematic. Surely it refers to GlassFish version 3, EE6, which is wrong. I'd like to know if this is correct or not.